# Amazon AWS Pagination on bucket files

Tags: amazon-s3

I am storing images in Amazon S3 bucket. Assume the bucket has 3,000 images. When i call the `list_objects` it returns me all the 3,000 images in an array. So my question is can we do pagination on the bucket? for example return me 100 images and when user will click on 2nd page the `list_objects` should return other 100 images. This way the request will be faster and will work fine on slower internet connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Amazon S3` supports pagination, you have to use `keyMarker` and `maxResults` in `listObjects()` method to implement pagination -

Find out more about this on -

http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2010/12/23/amazon-s3-cfc-paged-lists/